# Is there a faster way to inset a bevelled face without shrinking the bevels?

Tags: bevel

The picture shows the desired inset (blue, bevel is unchanged), and undesired type (Red, bevel shrinks in toward center of face). The blue inset was achieved by selecting each vertex of the bevel on one of the four corners of this face, then G moving on the Z/Y axis. Red was using the inset face option on FaceTools.
I have LoopTools/MeshTools/Mira tools but I did not identify anything within them to do this easier/faster. Doing this on each corner is a bit time consuming and I am hoping there is a faster method, is there?

[image]

Comment: I did now, but that didn't seem to have any different effect than inset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should do it this way instead:

- Inset a quad:

[image]

- Bevel the new diagonal edge and you'll get the result you want:

[image]